# bad operan types for binary operator

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Trying to write some pretty simple code. When I try to compile I get an error saying:

```
"bad operan types for binary operator*** 
First type:java.lang.string
Second type: Double."
```

I'm fairly new to coding, what does this mean/can anyone help me?

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( "Welcome to the Diskusting CD Company online store!");

    System.out.println( "First Name: ");
    String s1=in.next();
    System.out.println( "Last Name: ");
    String s2=in.next();
    System.out.println( "How many CD's?");
    String s3=in.next();

    double CD= 15.99;
    System.out.println( "Cost is " + s3*CD );
```

Comment: Problem is you are trying to multiply string with double `System.out.println( "Cost is " + s3*CD );`, first convert s3 to numeric then multiply.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts by editing the useful content out of it.

Answer (score 1):

`s3` is a `String`. You can't just multiply it with a `double`. Instead, you could input the number of CDs as an `int`:

```
System.out.println( "How many CD's?");
int numCDs = in.nextInt();
// Here --------^

double CD = 15.99;
System.out.println( "Cost is " + numCDs * CD);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mureinik pointed out, you need to make the string a double before you multiply. Just to comment briefly on why this is, consider what would happen if you tried to do `"abc" * 10` - it's not clear exactly what should happen in this case.

In general, Java's type system tries to make sure that the operations you try to do make sense for what kind of object you're doing them on. `abc * 10` doesn't make sense.

`10 * 10` makes sense because they're the same type (`int`).

`10 * 0.50` makes sense, even though one is an `int` and one is a `double`', because there's an obvious way to convert an `int` to a `double`. (Note that the converse is *not* true in general).